# comparing rows of two tables in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

Can anyone provide me a code for the following problem:

I have two tables in the sql server. Both tables have same number of fields and field names. If i am considering the two tables as ActualData and TempData,I need to update the data in ActualData table with that of data in the TempData using the column 'databaseID', i.e. for example if following tis the TempData table

```
DatabaseID | FirstName |  MiddleName    
277459 | VALINDA | CLAY         
283934 | LAURA | MARIE          
2.7E+13 | Jamie | Hawley
```

I need to find the row in the ActualData table with the same databaseID as that of row in the TempData and replace the entire record with that of the record in the TempData  table.And, if we dont find the record in the ActualData , then we need to add that record from TempData into the ActualData. this needs to be done for all the records in the TempData. 
How can i do that?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: You have pretty much described exactly what `MERGE` does.  I would suggest you start investigating with the documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Comment: Martin Smith-- Iam using Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want an UPDATE with a JOIN:

```
UPDATE A
SET
    A.FirstName = B.FirstName 
   ,A.MiddleName = B.Middlename
FROM
    ActualData A
    JOIN
    TempData B ON A.databaseID = B.databaseID
```

And an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO ActualData 
SELECT *
FROM TempData 
WHERE databaseID  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT databaseID  FROM ActualData)
```

Given that you have 110 fields, you may want to DELETE then INSERT, since you can do both without listing out columns:

```
DELETE FROM ActualData 
WHERE databaseID  IN (SELECT DISTINCT databaseID FROM ActualData)
```

Then do the INSERT above after the DELETE.  Not aware if there is a way to UPDATE with a JOIN without listing columns.

Comment: The OP also asked for an insert if the record wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 update ad
 set FirstName = td.FirstName,
     Middlename = td.MiddleName
 from ActualData ad
 inner join TempData td
 on ad.DatabaseID = td.DatabaseId
 where ad.FirstName != td.FirstName or ad.MiddleName != td.MiddleName

 insert into ActualData (DatabaseId, FirstName, MiddleName)
 select td.DatabaseId, td.FirstName, td.MiddleName
 from TempData td 
 left outer join ActualData ad on td.DatabaseId = ad.DatabaseId
 where ad.DatabaseId is null
```

Comment: How do we do it for all the records in the TempData? there are around 10k records in the tempdata table.

Comment: That will do it for every record in TempData that has a matching DatabseID with different data, and every record in TempData that does not have a matching record in ActualData.  Just try it.

Comment: Thanks wagregg. But in the example table i only have 3 field whereas in the original tables there are more than 100 fields. So, how do we set the values for all the fields?

Comment: You would need to add each field to the update clause and if you want, each field to the where clause.  Or, you could delete all the records from actual that exist in Temp and then reinsert everything from temp.

Comment: I added the DELETE to my answer after seeing your comment about 110 fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update a Set
     FirstName = t.FirstName,
     LastName = t.LastName,
     etc.
From ActualData a
    Join TempData t
        On t.DatabaseId = a.DatabaseId
-- -----------------------------------
Insert ActualData(DatabaseId, 
    FirstName, LastName,
    etc. ...)
Select DatabaseId, 
    FirstName, LastName,
    etc.
From tempData t
Where Not exists
    (Select * From ActualData
     DatabaseId = t.DatabaseId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an update/insert command like so (compatible with sql 2000 and above)

```
Update ActualData
Set FirstName = TempData.FirstName,
MiddleName = TempData.MiddleName
FROM ActualData
INNER JOIN TempData ON ActualData.DatabaseId = TempData.DatabaseId

insert into ActualData(DatabaseId, FirstName, MiddleName)
SELECT TempData.DatabaseId, TempData.FirstName, TempData.MiddleName
FROM TempData
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActualData ON ActualData.DatabaseId = TempData.DatabaseId
WHERE ActualData.DatabaseId IS NULL
```

Or you can use the merge command

Comment: thanks saamorim. how do i set the values if i have around 110 fields?

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic, then you should create a dynamic sql statement based on the syscolumns. To query the syscolumns do a select name from sys.columns where id = object_id('ActualData'). Since I don't like dynamic sql, normally I query the sys.columns for the column name and paste it at excel and apply the formula =A1 & ",  = TempData." & A1 that will give you the body of the update for the all the 100 columns. Hope I helped